# D3 Line chart with ordinal scale issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem with a ordinal scale in D3 and a line chart. I get a Array "Labels[]" with formatted Strings and I will "reference" this strings to my X-Axis. How can I realize this in an easy manner? My Code below does not work...my Data-Domain are all entries in the Labels Array opposed to the Range of my Chart !?! thank u...

0: "15.08.2013 00:15"
1: "15.08.2013 00:30"
2: "15.08.2013 00:45"
3: "15.08.2013 01:00"
4: "15.08.2013 01:15"
5: "15.08.2013 01:30"
6: "15.08.2013 01:45"
7: "15.08.2013 02:00"

```
  xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
             .rangePoints([0, chartWidth], 0.5)
             .domain(Labels.map(function (d, i) {
                       Labels[i];
                   }))

     xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
             .scale(xScale)
             .orient("bottom");

     var line = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function (d, i) {
                  return xScale(Labels[i])
               })
               .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.Value) })
                  .interpolate("linear");
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted code, the domain is not being configured correctly because your map function isn't returning values.  But even if it was returning a value, it isn't needed anyway.  You would be simply returning a copy of the `Labels` array exactly as it is.  If you're not doing a transformation of the array then just pass it in directly:

```
xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangePoints([0, chartWidth], 0.5)
    .domain(Labels);
```